# SAS: Creating Averages for all combinations of a given set of variables

Tags: sas

I would be very thankful if you could give me some hints (how to do or what procedures to have a look at) 
on the following issue:

If, for example, I have a dataset that contain (for each brand) 4 character variables and 3 numerical variables, then I would like to calculate several averages of numerical variables based on all possible combinations of character variables (whether some of characer variables are missing or not).

```
 Brand  Char1 Char2 Char3 Char4 NumVar1 NumVar2 NumVar3
    A   a   xx  3   a   0.471   0.304   0.267
    A   b   xy  3   s   0.086   0.702   0.872
    A   c   xz  3   a   0.751   0.962   0.080
    A   d   xx  2   s   0.711   0.229   0.474
    A   a   xy  3   a   0.160   0.543   0.256
    A   b   xz  1   s   0.200   0.633   0.241
    A   c   xx  3   a   0.765   0.511   0.045
    A   d   xy  4   s   0.397   0.815   0.950
    A   a   xz  1   a   0.890   0.757   0.483
    A   b   xx  3   a   0.575   0.625   0.341
    A   c   xy  3   a   0.595   0.047   0.584
    A   d   xz  1   s   0.473   0.806   0.329
    A   a   xx  2   s   0.062   0.161   0.018
    A   b   xy  2   s   0.935   0.990   0.072
    A   c   xz  4   s   0.564   0.490   0.112
    A   d   xx  2   a   0.251   0.228   0.215
    A   a   xy  4   a   0.551   0.778   0.605
    A   b   xz  1   s   0.887   0.392   0.866
    A   c   xx  1   s   0.238   0.569   0.245
    A   d   xz  1   a   0.736   0.961   0.627
```

Thus, I want to compute the following (written not in the sas notations, but just logically):

```
%let numeric_var = NumVar1 NumVar2 NumVar3; *macro of all numerical variables;

*compute mean values for each NumVar by all combinations of Char.variables;

compute mean(&numeric_var) by Char1 Char2 Char3 Char4 
compute mean(&numeric_var) by Char1 Char2 Char3 
compute mean(&numeric_var) by Char1 Char2 
compute mean(&numeric_var) by Char1 
compute mean(&numeric_var) by Char1 Char2       Char4
compute mean(&numeric_var) by Char1             Char4
compute mean(&numeric_var) by Char1       Char3 Char4  
etc.
```

Is there any more efficient way in sas to compute all these averages than just type all these combinations by hand?

In principle, at the end I would like to merge two datasets: one dataset as given above; and another dataset with only Character Variables (Brand  Char1 Char2 Char3 Char4) and missing values for some of them. That is why I want to calculate averages of numerical variables over all possible combnations of character variables

Many thanks in advance for any ideas.

Best,
Vlada

Comment: There's nothing wrong with crossposting the same question on multiple forums, but you might note that you did so that if you get a better answer in one place, searchers finding them on the other forum are able to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to do some reading about `PROC MEANS`, one of my favorite SAS procedures.  For example, consider this:

```
data have;
   input Brand $ Char1 $ Char2 $ Char3 $ Char4 $
         NumVar1 NumVar2 NumVar3;
   datalines;
    A   a   xx  3   a   0.471   0.304   0.267
    A   b   xy  3   s   0.086   0.702   0.872
    A   c   xz  3   a   0.751   0.962   0.080
    A   d   xx  2   s   0.711   0.229   0.474
    A   a   xy  3   a   0.160   0.543   0.256
    A   b   xz  1   s   0.200   0.633   0.241
    A   c   xx  3   a   0.765   0.511   0.045
    A   d   xy  4   s   0.397   0.815   0.950
    A   a   xz  1   a   0.890   0.757   0.483
    A   b   xx  3   a   0.575   0.625   0.341
    A   c   xy  3   a   0.595   0.047   0.584
    A   d   xz  1   s   0.473   0.806   0.329
    A   a   xx  2   s   0.062   0.161   0.018
    A   b   xy  2   s   0.935   0.990   0.072
    A   c   xz  4   s   0.564   0.490   0.112
    A   d   xx  2   a   0.251   0.228   0.215
    A   a   xy  4   a   0.551   0.778   0.605
    A   b   xz  1   s   0.887   0.392   0.866
    A   c   xx  1   s   0.238   0.569   0.245
    A   d   xz  1   a   0.736   0.961   0.627
run;

proc means noprint data=have completetypes;
   class Char1 Char2 Char3 Char4;
   var NumVar1 NumVar2 NumVar3;
   output out=want mean=mNumVar1 mNumVar2 mNumVar3;
run;
```

As written, the procedure will create an output data set named "want" with one observation for every combination of the variables listed in the **"class"** statement and with the MEAN statistic for each variable listed in the **"var"** statement.  In this example, there will be 300 observations (which you will note is larger than the original data set).

Additionally, the output data set will contain two automatic variables:

- **_*FREQ*_** - The number of observations in the combination
- **_*TYPE*_** - An identifier for the specific combination (based on the **CLASS** variables)

The **_*TYPE*_** variable will be especially useful in your case.  It's a numeric value based on the number of variables listed in the **class** statement.  Because you have four class variables, **_*TYPE*_** will have 16 values ranging from 0 to 15.  For example, the twelve observations that account for the combinations of variables **Char1** and **Char2** will have **_*TYPE*_=12**.

[**Here is a link**](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0f0fjpjeuco4gn1ri963f683mi4.htm) to the Online Docs for PROC MEANS in SAS version 9.3.

Comment: As Joe mentions below you should probably use `missing` to capture any combinations with missing variables.

Answer (score 3):

PROC MEANS should accomplish what you need, assuming I understand your problem.

```
proc means data=have;
class char1 char2 char3 char4;
types char1*char2*char3*char4 
      char1*char2*char3 
      char2*char3*char4 ... etc... ; *or use the various WAYS statements to get all combinations of a particular number of variables, or use _ALL_ to get all combinations;
var num1 num2 num3;
output out=want mean=;
run;
```

If the character variables might have missing values, then you need to use /missing; on the CLASS statement.

(Largely crossposted from SAS-L)